# Why aren't all my IAM groups listed in the GCP Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am an Azure customer researching GCP. I have only previously used GCP to manage "Sign in with Google".

Today I setup a new Google Identity and then ran partway through the Identity & Organisation "wizard" steps before stopping when it wanted me to make virtual cloud networks(!?) -- seemed excessive, I'm just trying to kick the tyres.

Anyway, the wizard made me setup several groups. Now, under IAM & Admin > IAM, View by [Principals], I can see a table and two of my groups are listed with their roles.

When I visit Groups on the left, I see another table with 7 groups listed, 2 that were system created and 2 that were also listed on the IAM page.

Why would IAM hide the other 3? There doesn't seem to be a way to add them or edit their roles, and there are no paging controls and no filters applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the groups manually. Although you might expect all the groups to be listed so that you can manage their roles, they are not; it doesn't work like that.

- Click ADD at the top of the IAM page and enter the email address of the group - do not expect auto-complete here, Google have not added that basic feature either.
- Select a role (add any more roles) and click SAVE.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're viewing IAM under Project Level, Only users or Groups has been created/managed on Project Level end will be shown on your IAM Page.

On Group Page, It will show other groups on other project as well under the selected Organization. Only Group Owners can be modify/managed Group accounts.

**Viewing and editing group details**

To view and edit the details of a group, including the group name, description, and membership, follow these steps:

1. In the Cloud Console, go to the Groups page.
2. Find the group whose details you want to view, click the Moremore_vert button in that row, and then click View group details.
3. To edit the group name or description, type your new name or description in the Group name or Group description field and click Save.
4. To edit the group's membership, do the following:

**To add members**: Click person Add members at the top of the page. Enter the names of the members you want to add, choose their Google Groups roles, then click Add to add them to the group.

**Note**: *When you add a member to a Google group, they inherit all IAM roles granted to that group, regardless of their Google Groups role.
To remove members: Select the checkboxes next to the names of the members you want to remove, then click delete Remove members at the top of the page.*

**To remove members**: Select the checkboxes next to the names of the members you want to remove, then click delete Remove members at the top of the page.

For more docs and guides, You can refer on links below: 
[Manage access to projects, folders, and organizations](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access?hl=en) 
[Managing groups in the Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/groups-in-cloud-console?hl=en) 
[Understanding roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles?hl=en)

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time. Only your first sentence is relevant, I think. I have no projects yet. I think I've found the answer myself! But thanks.